# indenting input text in same line as above

Tags: html, css

**[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fcsTM/)**

I have the following html...

```
<div>
<input type="radio" value="some value">some text here<br />
<input type="radio" value="some value">some text here and long<br />
</div>
```

the div has a width of 110 pixels. when some text go below it should be at the same line like this.

```
o some text
o some text
  and logn
```

Comment: Can you wrap `<input type="radio">` ?

Comment: @SonuJoshi no. I can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can done by adding a few css to your code.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <input type="radio" value="some value" />
    <label>some text here</label>
    <br />
    <input type="radio" value="some value" />
    <label>some text here and long</label>
    <br />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
div {
    width: 110px;
}
input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
}
label {
    float: left;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/fcsTM/5/)

Comment: I have just floated my input and it get worked. Thanks for your idea. n + 1

Comment: @C-Link I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting it on tables like this:

```
<div style="width: 110px;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" value="some value"></td>
            <td>some text here</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="radio" value="some value"></td>
            <td>some text here and long</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like only possible solution to me.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qKJjL/)

```
div{
    width: 110px;
    position:relative;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    position:absolute;
    left: -20px;
}
```

or

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qKJjL/)

```
div{
    width: 110px;
    position:relative;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
input[type="radio"]{
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```